# matplotlib works with default python but not python3.5 on debian

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib, debian, python-3.5

I have this issue. I think it's best described when I show you my bash commands that I used to produce the problem. See here:

```
josch@oogway:~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> #works



josch@oogway:~$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Apr 26 2017, 21:03:53) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>> #what??
```

Matplotlib was installed by:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

The "default" python came with my OS installation, python3.5 was downloaded and then compiled/installed from source.

Can anyone help? Tried to solve it myselve for 2 hours now but google can't find answer

Edit: I'm trying to install a "second pip" that works with my second installation of Python, which is Python3.5. My default-Python that is managed by the OS is Python 2.7.9. Now, as suggested I did:

```
joschua@oogway:~/Downloads$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

and then:

```
python3.5 get-pip.py
```

which gave me:

```
joschua@oogway:~/Downloads$ python3.5 get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Comment: Try this:  sudo apt-get install python3-pip, then sudo pip3 install matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pip3 with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and then try installing matplotlib with:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: nope, first one works finde, second just tells me that there is nothing to be done since everything's into place yet

Answer (score 0):

So, you installed python3.5 from source. What version of Debian are you using? (I suppose Jessie).

If you want to install packages for this Python interpreter, you must have a pip that actually uses it. Two solutions:

1. It is installed. If so,

   ```
   python3.5 -m pip
   ```

   will work and you can install packages with

   ```
   python3.5 -m pip install matplotlib
   ```

   or

   ```
   python3.5 -m pip install --user matplotlib
   ```
2. It is not installed. You must install it following the instructions at https://packaging.python.org/installing/#requirements-for-installing-packages

apt-get will not install the appropriate pip for your needs. It will only install a pip that is related to the python3 (3.4 for jessie I believe) that is also in the apt-get system.

EDIT: in light of the update, you need also to re-compile python3.5 with zip enabled.

Comment: although this could solve my problem, but my system doesnt let me install a "second pip" besides the first one

Comment: Please post the actual error messages. To install the "new" pip, you need to call it with the python3.5 Also, what are the replies to the tests I propose?

Answer (score 0):

I actually could solve the problem now.

See this link for a reasonable description on how to run two different versions of python on the same system (and as @Pierre de Buyl suggested) use two different pip versions on the same system

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140815081557-89781742-how-to-install-and-use-python-with-different-versions-on-same-linux-machine

Comment: Nice on solving it. But I run two python environments (2.7.9 and 3.4.2) and didn't have to anything other than install them (via apt-get) and execute the specific commands for each of the installed environments. Such as pip for 2.7.9 and pip3 for 3.4.2.